# Setting CKEditor size for the user

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a callback or anything I can use so that when a user resizes CKEditor I can save the new size in a cookie and reset the editor size when they next open the screen.

All the suggestions I've found so far have been settings in the config, rather than for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there's a method [`editor.resize()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-resize), which allows to resize the editor (i.e. with dimensions from a cookie).

Still the problem is: how to save dimensions, when user re-sizes the UI? There's [`editor#resize`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-resize) event fired, but for unknown reason, it does not pass any information about dimensions, which makes it pretty useless.

So right now, I'd suggest to override `editor.resize()`, which is called when user interacts with the resizer. Then, the intercepted dimensions can be reverted back with the same method:

```
var width, height,
    savedWidth, savedHeight;

var defaultResize = CKEDITOR.editor.prototype.resize;

CKEDITOR.editor.prototype.resize = function( w, h ) {
    // Intercept dimensions when user resizes the UI.
    width = w;
    height = h;
    defaultResize.apply( this, arguments );
};

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    toolbarGroups: [ { name: 'basicstyles' } ],
    resize_dir: 'both',
    on: {
        resize: function( evt ) {
            console.log( 'Editor was resized!' );
            console.log( '...but editor#resize does not pass dimensions in evt.data so it is useless :(' );
        }
    }
} );

function save() {
    savedWidth = width;
    savedHeight = height;
    console.log( 'saving', savedWidth, savedHeight );
}

function restore() {
    editor.resize( savedWidth, savedHeight );
    console.log( 'restoring', savedWidth, savedHeight );    
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/Lh5vt/)